# Настройка wccp2 cat3550+squid+centos6.8

Tags: centos, squid, cisco

Ребят, неделю убил, гугл не спасает. Возникла проблема при настройке кэша, сразу к конфигам:

## cat3550

```
ip subnet-zero
ip routing
ip wccp web-cache
!
!.....
interface FastEthernet0/12
 description Link to Cache
 no switchport
 ip address 33.33.33.33 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 description Link to LocalNet
 no switchport
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 ip wccp web-cache redirect in
!
```

## squid

```
 http_port 33.33.33.31:3128 transparent
 # -------------------------------------
 # WCCPv2 parameters
 # -------------------------------------
 wccp2_router 33.33.33.33
 wccp2_forwarding_method l2
 wccp2_return_method l2
 wccp2_service standard 0
```

## iptables

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dprot 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
```

После перезагрузки `squid` появляется вот это на 30 сек, потом пропадает

```
WCCP Client information:
        WCCP Client ID:          33.33.33.31
        Protocol Version:        2.0
        State:                   NOT Usable
        Redirection:             L2
        Packet Return:           L2
        Packets Redirected:    0
        Connect Time:          00:00:00
        Assignment:            MASK
```

## Логи на cisco

```
*Mar  1 04:29:44.762: VEGAS/WCCP:  Lost service notification
*Mar  1 04:29:44.762: VEGAS/WCCP:  Lost service CE (33.33.33.31) from  vegas_wccp_update_service_lost
*Mar  1 04:29:44.762: VEGAS/WCCP:  Cannot find CE (33.33.33.31) to remove service
*Mar  1 04:30:34.762: VEGAS/WCCP:  Assignment Timeout Notification
*Mar  1 04:30:34.762: VEGAS/WCCP:  Free all TCAM entries
```

Из логов понятно, что видимо `squid` не отвечает, но как и куда смотреть?

Comment: Решили задачу каким-то образом?

Comment: @Ruslan помнится что решил, но вот каким образом не помню. Но помню что пришлось пере собирать squid, так как какой-то модуль не был включен из коробки. Года полтора как сменил квалификацию, точнее сказать не могу.
В свое время один мудрый человек скидывал вот такой архив. Может найдете что для себя, но я без него обошелся
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Gxib2YKv4xcVR3dHl5ZjNHWGVBa1NPZzhSOHl3R2FxTnh3